# Any ideas on tuning single stream tcp performance?

Tags: tcp, performance-tuning

I'm a newbie to TCP tuning and would really like some pointers to possible solutions.

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 server with maximum bandwidth of 30Mbps. But simple downloading like `scp` or `wget` can only reach 600-700KB/s.

When checking with `iperf3`, I found that only parallel streaming (like `iperf3 -P 6`) can achieve the full bandwidth, while single stream transfer is stuck with at most about 0.68MB/s.

Any way to work around this?

Comment: I hate to tell you, but at this point you do NOT look for tuning but need to find out where it bugs out. 30Mb to 600kb smells to either crappy programming or - a network related bug. Or some network equipment blocking single stream throughput (like a firewall of the ISP or so).

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. Well it's about 5Mb (600Kilobytes * 8). But I think you might be correct, since this only appeared recently. About two weeks ago `wget` could still reach 3MB/s, but on the other hand I haven't made any change to the server for weeks.

Comment: My main point is that it is TOO LOW. There is no way that a proper programmed tcp link goes to 600kb from 30mb. THis is like "need to tune my porsche, only goes 40km/h" - that is not tuning, that is repairing.